# When will Zombie Pigmen start spawning?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing in a world in Survival Mode. I have known that Zombie Pigmen drop gold and even golden swords when killed. I expect to spawn at night like regular non-friendly mobs. But they don't seem to ***ever*** spawn at night.

I even tried trapping a pig in with a zombie because I was that desperate! So what are the conditions necessary to be able for Zombie Pigmen to spawn? Do I have set my difficulty level to hard or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the pocket edition wikia page, they spawn after you build a nether reactor, and come in waves of 2 or 3. When you build a nether reactor, about 6 or 7 will spawn. Read this article if you would like to learn more: [Minecraft PE: Pigmen](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Zombie_Pigmen)